# Why did GCC optimizes important assignment, making it into a different program behavior?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, variable-assignment

So, I am making a C program for my console interpreter to detect which type is it, then return it to `typeret` and store the pointer into the void pointer `retpoint`.
Now, what I am asking is not what is in the code, but rather **why** GCC optimizes this assignment in my function `eval`. I want to know why GCC optimizes something that is actually important.

```
int eval(wchar_t *expr) {
    // ....
    
    if (expr[0] == L'\'' && expr[csize - 1] == L'\'') { // <-- Ignore this.
        expr[csize - 1] = 0;
        typeret         = 0;
        
        retpoint    = (expr + 1);
    } else if (strin(L".", expr)) { // <-- Ignore this.
        typeret     = 2;
    } else {
        typeret     = 1;
        tvar        = _wtoi(expr); // <-- Here is the problem.
        retpoint    = &tvar;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code with the GCC command, `gcc -Wsomewarning -o cim.exe cim.c -Os -s -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O3`, the assignment is not detected (even without `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections`, the assignment is not detected too).

But, when I change the code that involves around `tvar` OR around `_wtoi`, the assignment is not ignored. Here is the example code whereby the assignment is not ignored.

```
int eval(wchar_t *expr) {
    int
        tvar; // If I set tvar to N, then the assignment is still ignored (making tvar = N).

    // ....

    if (expr[0] == L'\'' && expr[csize - 1] == L'\'') { // <-- Ignore this.
        expr[csize - 1] = 0;
        typeret         = 0;

        retpoint    = (expr + 1);
    } else if (strin(L".", expr)) { // <-- Ignore this.
        typeret     = 2;
    } else {
        typeret     = 1;
        tvar        = _wtoi(expr); // <-- Here is the problem.
        wprintf(L"%d", tvar); // or wprintf(L"%d", _wtoi(expr);
        retpoint    = &tvar;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, of course, if I use the `gcc -o cim.exe cim.c` (without optimization), the first code works fine; however, the size is four times bigger than the optimized one.

**Note**

I am sure there is no undefined behavior in this program, and I am sure that I have given the data correctly.

The `typeret` and `retpoint` is a global data, whereas the `tvar` is a local variable.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that I used GCC version (tdm64-1) 4.9.2 in Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (a) Edit the question to provide a [mre]. (b) Explain what you mean by “the assignment is not detected.” State specific behavior you observe, such as generated assembly code or something in the object file or the behavior of the resulting program, that indicates the assignment is or is not “detected.”

Comment: You have `retpoint` pointing to a local variable. It doesn't appear that you ever dereference it before `eval` returns.    If you dereference it after `eval` returns, then you do have UB since `tvar`'s lifetime has ended.  If you don't dereference it, then the assignment is unnecessary because nobody will ever see the value.  So I'm pretty sure the compiler is right here.

Comment: (Incidentally though, why are you using such an old version of gcc?)

Comment: @NateEldredge, dude, I forgot about that....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I suck at programming. The answer is in the comment.

Comment: If your code does not work with the optimizations, it means that you have a very probable UB or other problem in **your** code. Do not blame compiler, blame yourself. Focus on your code

Comment: @0___________, yes, I forgot about what NateEldredge mentions.

Comment: @NateEldredge, maybe because I download it using Dev-C++ (even though I use Notepad++).

Comment: @FaranAiki You can delete your question if you think it is now useless for anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, the variable `tvar` is not accessed, neither directly nor through the pointer `retpoint`, between the assignment `tvar = _wtoi(expr);` and when the function `eval` returns, and after that the lifetime of `tvar` ends because it is local.  And you are only allowed to access `tvar` during its lifetime. So the compiler has every right to optimize out the assignment because it cannot have any effect on a correct program.

If it does change the behavior of your program, then you probably have undefined behavior somewhere.  Perhaps you are dereferencing the pointer `retpoint` after `eval` returns.  That is definitely UB.  In general, setting a global pointer to point to a local variable, and leaving it there after the function returns, is very suspicious.